# mysqlcheck return error message mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect

Tags: mysql, access-denied, mysqlcheck

I am doing mysqlcheck command such as `root@com-dev:/var/lib/mysql# mysqlcheck databasedirectory` and you would think root will have access to any file system, but it returns this error message not sure what to do.

> mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) when trying to connect

How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find solution anywhere in the web, so I tried and found this solution: `root@com-dev:/var/lib/mysql# mysqlcheck -u root -p databasedirectory` You need to pass in username and password of db credentials as options and just as you run mysql command.

Comment: The above didn't work for me, but I ran: c:\ Program Files\MySql Server 5.7\bin\mysqlcheck -u root -p -r mydbname